# Is it possible to use array values to define variable?

Tags: programming-languages, pascal

What i mean is something like:
I have 2 array var and type, you can input the name of the variable on the var array and type of variable on the type array(type depend on language used), then i want to use the value from these array to define varriable i.e:

Var[1] as type[1]
Var[2] as type[2]

Is it possible to do something like that?

Second question:
Can i auto increase variable name which contain number? I want to do something that work like array but using normal variable. For example :
I have 10 variable f1~f10
Then i want to loop it until all variable filled, something like

For a=1 to 10 do
{
 f(a) = a
}

Sorry if it is hard to understand i cant explain it very well. I want to know is possible in general programming, specifically pascal because i study alghoritm using this language in college.

Comment: It's not possible in Pascal, no.  That's not the way the language is designed, nor should it be.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? The way that you are trying to do it is possible in lexical languages, but not pascal. However what you are trying to do will be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it that you are trying to do? The way that you are trying to do it is possible in lexical languages, but not pascal.

You can though look-up an array by name. This is sort of the opposite of what you asked, but in some ways very similar.

```
type
  MonthType = (January, February, March, April,
              May, June, July, August, September,
              October, November, December);
```

Then use this to look up an array

```
ord(December)
```

Gives `11`, so you could use it to look up days in month.
By pascal programming skills are useless, so someone else can fix and extend this answer.

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Enumerated_types

Comment: is this the  answer for 1st or both question? I think of using 'if' inside a loop for the second problem, something like input to variable f1 if a=1, in theory i think something like this is possible but havent tried it yet and the code will be very long i guess, is it possible?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Tell us that and we may be able to tell you how to do it. At present we can just tell you that your how, can not be done. (In pascal you can do anything that can be done in programming, but you have to chose the right hows.)

Comment: I want to do something like creating table in database, you enter how much field you want to create -> insert field name (i.e field1 = name), and then you insert the content of that field(name = john). I already able to do it up to here using array actually(still have abit problem when the content length is less than the field name the rest of the field name got carried to content i.e. Field = name, content = ab, the content become 'abme'

Comment: Update: the field name got carried only when saved to dat file

Comment: So that everyone can benefit, and you get a better answer. Can you put the clarification, into the question.

Comment: Actually you already answered my main question, that it is not possible to use array value to define variable in pascal but you can do it in lexical language. The last problem in my comment actually not really related to my main question, but i'll be glad if you can help solve it. The problem is as follow: i create a program to create a database but simpler you can create a number of field, give name to each field, and input the content for that field, and save it to dat file. I already create it but there is some problem when i input a content with length less than the field name

Comment: The remaining field name got carried to the content for example if i create a field 'name' and i input 'ab' as the content, the content become 'abme' in the dat file, but not changed if i use it inside the program. What is the cause?